# How to pass object as method parameter in vbscript

Tags: c#, object, vbscript

I trying make small test in vbscript so created very, very simple dll in C#(i am new) and want to use it in vbscript.

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace myNamespace
{
    public class myClass1
    {
        public string sVariable1="Variable content";
    }

    public class myClass2
    {
        public myClass1 myMethod2(myClass1 test)
        {
            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

and vbscript

```
Set oClass1 = CreateObject("myNamespace.myClass1")
Set oClass2 = CreateObject("myNamespace.myClass2")
WScript.Echo oClass1.sVariable1

Set return = oClass2.myMethod2(oClass1)
WScript.Echo return.sVariable1
```

after running vbscript, on console i have "Variable content" displayed by first echo and next i have error "microsoft vbscript runtime error invalid procedure call or argument: 'oClass2.myMethod2'".

Could I pass object in this way ?

Referring to the note of MK2. Problem is not the return type by method, because following code is working.

```
        public myClass1 myMethod2()
        {
            myClass1 test = new myClass1();
            return test;
        }
```

and vbs

```
Set return = oClass2.myMethod2()
```

now on console i have

```
Variable content
Variable content
```

But how to pass myClass1 object in vbs ?

Comment: Shouldn't you change this: **public myClass1 myMethod2(myClass1 test)**
 to this: **public myClass2 myMethod2(myClass1 test)**

Answer (score 0):

OK I found solution.
In C# as a param myMethod2 I declared ref to object and next I used type casting. Something like this:

```
    public myClass1 myMethod2(ref object refObject)
    {
        myClass1 test = (myClass1)refObject;
        return test;
    }
```

Now vbscript working perfectly. I hope it will be helpful for someone :)